# Proxies with ObjectContext (Model First)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

The use of proxies with EF 4.1 POCO is clear and straightfoward. But why to use (or not to use) proxies with EF 4.0 Model First, setting the property ctx.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = true?

The MSDN for the [ObjectContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.DATA.OBJECTS.OBJECTCONTEXTOPTIONS.PROXYCREATIONENABLED%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) states:

> With this flag set to true the Entity Framework will attempt to create proxies for your POCO entities. ProxyCreationEnabled flag is set to true by default.

OK, but what about Model First? I´m not using POCO and this property is available.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using POCO entities, then this flag is not used.

(Note that you can use POCO entities with ObjecContext and Model First.)